# Where can I fnd a header for this goofy chip

Tags: integrated-circuit

I got this chip and didn't realize the pins were not the normal spacing.

[image]

Anybody know where to find a header for it.

BTW the chip is a re-issue of the old sound chip SN76477

[image]

Comment: What company is doing the re-issue? Where are they being sold? Thanks.

Comment: You guys made go dig through the shop to find my old project that used that chip. Luckily my soldering skills have improved a bit since then. [Sound Synth Project on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/loco539/4433957405/in/set-72157623623035876/) That was a fun chip! Sounds like they found a few options for your special package size. Have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like the 0.070 spacing on 600mil centers. Mill-max makes
a socket for that. See 
http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=ED90227-ND

After you get the socket I would route a slot in the Vector board with a 
Dremel tool and glue the socket in place. Run short jumper wires from the socket
pins to pins on the Vector board. (like Vector K24A or T42-1)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what it is thanks Jluciani except it's .4 http://es.digikey.com/1/1/790559-ic-socket-30-pin-400-hi-density-117-43-430-41-005000.html for other peoples reference.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have there is a "thin body" SN76477N. Radio Shack/Tandy had it "custom packaged" in the USA.

It being an antique, I doubt you'll find anyone selling an adapter.

You could make one...

Buy a piece of copper clad board, a fine tipped etch-resist pen and some etchant.

Drill holes spaced correctly for the chip, draw on the tracks with the pen, submerse in etchant until all of the unwanted copper is gone.

Comment: I tried soldering to the pins themself and that was a loosing process, I didn't want to spend 3 hours working on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a header, but it is a cheap and easy way to get standard spacing: http://www.bgmicro.com/index.asp?PageAction=VIEWPROD&ProdID=12925&HS=1

They also have the chips themselves:
http://www.bgmicro.com/index.asp?PageAction=VIEWPROD&ProdID=12924&HS=1

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the photo, but looks like common 0.1" pin spacing to me.  So it should plug into a breadboard just fine.  If it's the SN76477NF, which is the 0.4" across narrow version of the chip, then yes, a normal socket (that come in 0.3" & 0.6" widths and is what I assume you mean by "header") won't work.

But you can take a [28-pin 0.6" width socket like this one from Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&productId=40301), cut it into two pieces along the three cross-braces, and remake it into a 0.4" width socket.

Comment: <img src="http://www.themountainfold.com/test/IMG_1119.png">

Comment: weird.  that's like a 0.064" pin spacing?  wacky.  If I had that chip, I'd probably make my own socket out of a cut up machined wire-wrap socket.  The longer wire-wrap pins would let you bend the socket holes around to match the oddball pin spacing. Once you get all the socket holes aligned, fix the spacing with hot glue.  Pretty hacky though.

Comment: 14 pins per inch, so 1/14" pin spacing. Yuck

Answer (score -3):

Old thread, but I found this IC socket that should fit. I have this chip also and it doesn't fit a breadboard, hopefully the socket will allow a little more space to fit it.
http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=148241958&uq=635331715231561752

Comment: Link is broken.